# Inserting multiple records and updating identity column in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

i have to insert multiple records into a table and in the mean time needed to insert the identity column of the first table in to another table.Can i do it avoiding loop?

### Edited

```
   i have two tables named StudentMaster and StudentSujects.

  First Table structure is (StudentID int Identity(1,1),StudentName varchar(100))

  Second table structure is (SubjectID int Identity(1,1),StudentID int,SubjectName varchar(100)).
```

StudentID in the 'StudentSujects' table is the Identity column of first table 'StudentMaster'.

```
INSERT INTO StudentMaster
                            (
                                 StudentName
                            )
                    SELECT       StudentName
                    FROM OPENXML(@hDoc,'/XML/Students')
                    WITH(    StudentName    varchar(100)    'StudentName')


   I am inserting multiple records in to the first table using the above query.I the mean time i have to insert the identity column of each row in to the second table.
```

Comment: Post the table structure, and expected data and what have you tried so far

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to output multiple columns/rows on an `INSERT` operation into a table variable.

Assuming your table that you're inserting into has an `IDENTITY` column called `ID`, you could have code something like this:

```
DECLARE @InsertedData TABLE (NewID INT, SomeOtherColumn.....)

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
OUTPUT INTO @InsertedData(NewID, SomeOtherColumn) Inserted.ID, Inserted.OtherColumn
VALUES(Val11, Val12, ..., Val1N),
      (Val21, Val22, ..., Val2N),
      ....
      (ValM1, ValM2, ..., ValMN)
```

Of course, you need to have *something* that allows you to identify which row in your second table to insert which value into - that's entirely dependent on your situation (and you didn't offer any explanation of that in your question).

But basically, using the `OUTPUT` clause, you can capture as much information as you need, including the newly assigned `IDENTITY` values, so that you can then do your second insert based on that information.